# How to extract data at the server end?

Tags: android, http, http-post

I have used the following code on my client side (Android emulator).

```
HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost("http://117.192.xxx.xxx:8080/System_Alpha/");
List pairs=new  ArrayList();
String strUsername=username.getText().toString();
String strPassword=password.getText().toString();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", strUsername));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", strPassword));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
HttpResponse response= client.execute(httpPost);
```

My question is, at the server end, how can I extract these values? That is, the username and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what you have on the server side.

Say: if you have a java servlet, you just retrieve the necessary data in your `doGet` (resp. `doPost`) method:

```
final String userName = (String) request.getParameter("userName");
final String password = (String) request.getParameter("password");
```

**Update 1**
Here is an example of a simple servlet that authenticates a user with the two parameters above, and sends back an xml response:

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/xml");
        final ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        try
        {
            final String userName = (String) request.getParameter("userName");
            final String password = (String) request.getParameter("password");
            final boolean authenticated = login(userName, password);
            if (authenticated)
                out.println("<login><status>SUCCESS</status></login>");
            else
                out.println("<login><status>FAIL</status></login>");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            out.println("<login><status>ERROR</status></login>");
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        this.doGet(request, response);
    }

    private boolean login(final String userName, final String password)
    {
        // TODO: authenticate the user and return the result: true/false
    }
}
```

In your `web.xml` you declare your servlet by writing:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>[yourpackagename].LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

where `[yourpackagename]` is the package where your `LoginServlet` is declared.

This way, if all these are in a web application named `Try`, and you deploy it, you can access your login servlet over http at `http://localhost:8080/Try/LoginServlet/`.

**Update 2**
To retrieve the data from the HttpResponse, you need:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
final InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
```

You handle this `InputStream` depending on what kind of data it contains.

If you need the `String` value of the response entity:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
final String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Comment: @rekaszeru, I don't have a servlet on my server. All I want to do at the server end is, extract the data sent and put it in a Database. My plan is use to use sockets and listen on port 8080.

Comment: what kind of server / container backend engine do you have on server side? (what is your backend language? c#/asp? php? java/jsp?)

Comment: @rekaszeru, On my server, I have Apache running. I don't need a webpage, and hence I am not using jsp and the like...what I want is, my android device to communicate with the server through http directly through request/response. I'll be using Java at the server side.

Comment: Besides Apache (assume Http Server) you must have a Java servlet/service container there (to run your java classes), like Tomcat (also from Apache). You can then create either a simple (not published) web application, and implement a servlet there with the code above and the rest of the authentication (database, etc.), or you can create a web service for this same job, and deploy it under a service container, like Axis (which also runs in Tomcat as a web application).

Comment: @rekaszeru, Is it not possible to do it without the use of servlets?

Comment: :-? servlet being a server side code that hadles http requests, examine their parameters, and based on them serves with the appropriate http response..., and since you said you'd like this to be done over the http protocol..., i'd say no. But just don't be so scared, you said you'd use java on the server side --> you probably have some container there that is able to run java, so it's simple (you'll use a java servlet - which is a java class extending `HttpServlet' - and that's all you need to get it going).

Comment: I was able to get my android app to send request to the servlet. The servlet processed it. Now, how do I receive the reply from the server in my android app? Which method in the class HttpResponse will help me? Should I use HttpServletResponse on client side too?

Comment: That's great! Your code in your question is half-way there, you already have the `HttpResponse`. Please see my update for retrieving the input stream of it.